# Css class not working for Asp.Net MVC dropdownlist

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to apply css class for asp.net mvc dropdown list. It works for editorfor case but not for dropdownlistfor case. What may be the missing part from my code?

Working css class for dropdown

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.role, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

failing css class for drowdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.role, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Roles"], "role1", "role1"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: `new { @class = "form-control" }` not `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }`

Comment: Just use `new { @class = "form-control" }` for DDLF CSS attribute, because `EditorFor` doesn't have `htmlAttributes` but DDLF has it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//DropDownListFor: modelItem, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes
//EditorFor: modelItem, additionalViewData
```

If you "right click" the code and peek definition (in Visual Studio) you'll see the definitions. So if you use this, it should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.role, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Roles"], "role1", "role1"), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: ,null with overload is really interesting. Thanks.

Comment: If you put in "--- please select ---" instead of null, you'll see it's purpose in the dropdown.